# GWT 2: can I handle image resources as an array?

Tags: image, gwt, resources

In my GWT project I have some separate set of images. The most convinient thing is to handle this set of images as an ImageResource array. I.e. I want to have a method in my Resources interface that can return me an array of these ImageResources instances instead of returning them one by one.

Is it possible to code this in GWT 2.4?

ps
Yes, I understand that I can return them one by one and then create that array manually. But probably there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any interface for doing that.
But alternatively you could check out [ClientBundleWithLookup](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/resources/client/ClientBundleWithLookup.html).
Depending on your use case it might be of use for you.